# using google Dart with Google Maps JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dart

Is there a way to use JS api and frameworks like Google Maps JavaScript API, dojo within a dart project. pointers to some samples will be nice.

Answer (score 5):

I have used Alexandre Ardhuin's [google_maps](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps) package. Install it as a dependency:

```
dependencies:
  google_maps: any
```

Then import a few files in the HTML:

```html
<head>
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.10&sensor=false"></script>
  <link href="https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

**Note:** I had to use version 3.10 of the JS API -- be sure to specify that in the URL (as I did above), until the package has been updated to work with the latest version.

Then the actual HTML container for the map:

```html
<div class="map" style="width: 640; height: 640px;"></div>
```

Some imports:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;
import 'package:google_maps/js_wrap.dart' as jsw;
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';
```

Then the actual code:

```dart
js.scoped(() {
  var mapOptions = new MapOptions()
    ..mapTypeId = MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    ..center = new LatLng(60.987097,25.767059)
    ..zoom = 6;

  var map = new GMap(_root.query(".map"), mapOptions);

  var marker = new Marker(
    new MarkerOptions()
      ..position = new LatLng(60.987097,25.767059)
      ..map = map
      ..title = 'Foo'
  );

  var content = new DivElement();
  content.innerHtml = '''
<h3>Foo</h3>

<p>bar</p>
''';

  var infoWindow = new InfoWindow(
    new InfoWindowOptions()
      ..content = content
  );

  marker.on.click.add((e) {
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  jsw.retainAll([map, marker, infoWindow]);
});
```

The result is a map where I have marked my home city.

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: How come you don't need a 'key' parameter in the script tag? (API key)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [google_maps](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps) package to deal with [Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).

To deal with Js Api, you can use the [js](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js) package. See [Using JavaScript from Dart: The js Library](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/) for more informations.

Comment: I get 'Cannot find referenced source: package:google_maps/
 google_maps.dart'. I did pub install and i see google_maps/
 google_maps.dart under packages

Comment: I am on a mac osx 64 bit if it makes any difference

Comment: I don't have such problem (on linux)

Comment: import '../packages/js/js.dart' as js;
seems to work. am I missing any pub config. pub install works fine though.

Comment: Quite strange. Are you using the last version of editor/sdk ?